# z-index doesn't work with SetStyleAttributes

Tags: google-apps-script

I just noticed that whenever I used `SetStyleAttribute('z-index',x)` that the z-index was appropriately added to the inline style in the HTML.  However, when I used

```
SetStyleAttributes({
  'z-index': zIndex,
  ...other items});
```

it doesn't get added to the inline html and doesn't work as it should.  Has anyone else noticed this?

Answer (score 0):

try using zIndex (in camelCase). The '-' character is'nt supported. The .SetStyleAttribute does accept it but the developer reference from Google still talks about using the CSS attributes in camelCase ("fontSize", not "font-size").